# ExtJs autoLoad scripts not executed

Tags: html, extjs, extjs4

I have three files: form.html, report.html, console.html.  I am facing two problems with console.html page.

- I am trying to load 'report.html' but only static content is loaded,
  extJs components are not loaded or say script is not executed.
- I am trying to load 'form.html'. In this code, i am able to load form.html along with extJs components successfully. But the problem is that once tab2 is loaded, i am not able to activate/see tab1.
  Appreciate any help. Any example of autoLoad without any error will do.
  **Console.html is as below:**

```
<head>
    <title>Sample Console</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ExtJs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ExtJs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function() {
            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                renderTo: 'frmSampleConsole',
                split: true,
                height : '100%',
                width : '100%',
                layout:'border',
                defaults: {
                    collapsible: true,
                    split: true
                    //bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
                },
                items: 
                [
                    {
                        title: 'Report',
                        region : 'west',
                        width : 280,
                        autoLoad : 'report.html',
                        contentType: 'html',
                        scripts : true
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        id :'tabpanel',
                        xtype:'tabpanel',
                        title: 'Main Content',
                        collapsible: false,
                        region:'center',
                        items : [
                            {
                                id : 'tab1',
                                title: 'Tab1',
                                collapsible: false,
                                margins: '5 0 0 0',
                                activeTab:0,
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        html : 'Sample html content'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            { 
                                id :'tab2',
                                title : 'Tab2',  
                                layout : 'fit',
                                closable: true,
                                loader: {
                                    url: 'form.html',
                                    contentType: 'html',
                                    autoload: true,
                                    loadMask: true,
                                    scripts: true
                                },
                                listeners: {
                                    render: function(tab) {
                                        tab.loader.load();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = 'frmSampleConsole'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you cant load extjs library twice, this i not going to work. either your static content should stay static or you will need to use iframes.

Answer (score 0):

your need to set "`scripts: true,`" then your extjs script are work.